# woocommerce paypal after payment redirected many times

Tags: wordpress, pdf, woocommerce, paypal

when I make a payment with paypal on my site for a downloadable pdf book, the payment works well but I do not receive the email with the download link.
and after payment a google page is displayed with an error message redirection too many.
But when I look at the logs the email is sent but I don't receive it. However if I pay by credit card everything works. Do you have an idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I just updated the theme